# R sf Polygon subtract 1000 from x coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, sf

My aim is to subtract a value of 1000 from all x coordinates of an R sf object. How can I achieve this?

When running the following code the value 1000 is subtracted from all coordinates (x **and** y values):

```
library(sf)

# Create Polygon: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf1.html
p1 <- rbind(c(1000,1000), c(1000,2000), c(2000,2000), c(1000,1000))
pol <-st_polygon(list(p1))
pol_geom = st_sf(st_sfc(pol, crs = 4326))  
plot(pol_geom)

# Trying to subtract 1000 from all x coordinates
t <- st_geometry(pol_geom)
class(t)
lnd_geom <- t-1000
lnd_attrib <- pol_geom %>% st_set_geometry(NULL)
class(lnd_attrib)
pol_geom_new = st_sf(lnd_attrib, geometry = lnd_geom)
st_bbox(pol_geom)
st_bbox(pol_geom_new)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example:

```
library(sf)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

nc1 <- st_transform(nc[1, ], 32617)

nc2 <- st_geometry(nc1) - c(1000, 0)

plot(nc1[0], axes = T, reset = F)
plot(nc2, add = T, col = NA, border ='red')
```

See `sf` Vignette #3's section on [Affine Transformations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf3.html#affine_transformations) for more tricks.

Comment: is there a simple way to multiply the x and y coordinates with two different values. * c(0,-1) does not only multiply the y coordinates but also the x coordinates...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to subtract 1000 from the x coords. Here is how I would go about it:

```
library(sf)
p1 <- rbind(c(1000,1000), c(1000,2000), c(2000,2000), c(1000,1000))
pol <-st_polygon(list(p1))
pol_geom = st_sfc(pol, crs = 4326)  

# Getting the coordinates of pol_geom
coords = st_coordinates(pol_geom)
new_coords = coords[,1:2]
# Subtracting 1000 from the x-val
new_coords[,1] = new_coords[,1] - 1000
### Subtracting 1000 from the y-val
new_coords[,2] = new_coords[,2] - 1000
```

I took the coordinates of your polygon (using st_coordinates()) and created a new matrix (new_coords) with the x **and** y vals being subtracted by 1000.

Or you can just subtract x coords like this:

```
# Getting the coordinates of pol_geom
coords = st_coordinates(pol_geom)
new_coords = coords[,1:2]
# Subtracting 1000 from the x-val
new_coords[,1] = new_coords[,1] - 1000
### getting the original y-val
new_coords[,2] = new_coords[,2]
```

I then created a new polygon from those coordinates.

```
# Recreating the polygon from the new coords (with 1000 subtracted from x vals)
pol <-st_polygon(list(new_coords))
pol_geom = st_sfc(pol, crs = 4326)
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking, hopefully it helps!

Comment: @ Aliyan Haq If I  add a second polygon this solution doesn't work. It prints: Error in MtrxSet(x, dim, type = "POLYGON", needClosed = TRUE) : 
  polygons not (all) closed . Do you know how I can solve this?

New polygon dataset with 2 polygons:
p1 <- rbind(c(1000,1000), c(1000,2000), c(2000,2000), c(1000,1000))
p2 <- rbind(c(500,500), c(500,100), c(1000,1000), c(500,500))
pol <-st_polygon(list(p1, p2))
pol_geom = st_sfc(pol, crs = 4326)